# Error with these bootstrap tabs?

Tags: php, html, web, tabs

Okay, I am trying to add these tabs from twitter bootstrap, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I can't get these things to work! Some could please help me out?

My tab code..

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="my-tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="home">asdf</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">fasd</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="messages">.xzcv</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="settings">ert.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#tabs').tab();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('#tabs').tab('show');
});
```

You may also want to double check that you've got jQuery included in the header...

Answer (score 0):

You can activate individual tabs in several ways.

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show'); // Select tab by name
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show'); // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```